# Sort a list in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{
    "key1": {
        "element1": [1, 10, 5, 13, 4, 7]
    },
    "key2": {
        "element2": [3, 5, 2, 9, 12, 1]
    }
}
```

I want to sort the list `element1` and `element2` in a for loop (The real dictionary i have is more big), how i do that?

Comment: What you want to sort - main dictionary or the dictionaries inside it

Comment: I want to sort `element1` and `element2` in a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that the dictionary above is equal to `x`.
You then then do:

```py
for value in x.values():
    for elem_value in value.values():
         elem_value.sort()
```

Lists are mutatable, and so by changing the lists directory, you would change the overall dictionary,

Answer (score 1):

You will need a double loop because each element is an item of a dictionary, which is also an item of a dictionary.
Here is one approach.

```py
x = {
    "key1": {
        "element1": [1, 10, 5, 13, 4, 7]
    },
    "key2": {
        "element2": [3, 5, 2, 9, 12, 1]
    }
}

for _, elem in x.items():
   for _, lst in elem.items():
   lst.sort()
   
x
{'key1': {'element1': [1, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13]},
 'key2': {'element2': [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 12]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
data = {
    "key1": {
        "element1": [1, 10, 5, 13, 4, 7]
    },
    "key2": {
        "element2": [3, 5, 2, 9, 12, 1]
    }
}

for key,values in data.items():
    for k,v in values.items():
        data[key][k] = sorted(v)
        
print(data)
```

**Result:**

```
{
 'key1': 
   {
    'element1': [1, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13]
   }, 
 'key2': 
   {
    'element2': [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 12]
   }
 }
```